# results from ajax doesnt show up in my html template rendered with django

Tags: django, ajax

before I go into details about my problem, I just want to say I'm new in DJANGO/AJAX world, so if you think I can do what I want, with an easier/more efficient way, I'd be more than happy to hear it, thank you so much in advance.
I have a web page which contains a search bar, and a sort of complex table structure, we are supposed to be able to search an item using the search bar and show the relative result in the table using AJAX, without the page reload, I managed to write the AJAX CALL, send it to the view, get the result data in view, so far everything works well, I print the results in view, and it works fine I get the result, but once I render the template with the result data, the table's fields are empty. I don't know where did I go wrong. any help would be much appreciated.

this is the script that make the Ajax call(I use an AJAX call to show live search result, something like what google does on search,  and gave every result a class name of 'SearchResultItem')

```
$(document).on('click', 'a.SearchResultItem', e=>{
    e.preventDefault();
    targetAuthorityId = e.target.parentElement.id

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '../supremeWatchShowData/',
        data: {
            'csrfmiddlewaretoken': csrf,
            'authorityId': targetAuthorityId,
        },
        success: (res) =>{
            console.log(res)
        },
        error: (err)=>{
            console.log(err)
        }

    });

});
```

this is the view:

```
def supremeWatchShowData(request):
    is_ajax = request.headers.get('X-Requested-With') == 'XMLHttpRequest'
    if is_ajax: 
        authorityId = request.POST.get('authorityId')
        res = get_object_or_404(SourceData, id=authorityId)
        return render(request, 'ahromApp/supremeWatch.html', {'res': res})
    else:
        print("not an ajax request")

    return render(request, 'ahromApp/supremeWatch.html')
```

and in the template I write something like this :

```
<td>{{res.lprice}}</td>
```

how can I fix it?

something really interesting  here is that when I check in firefox inspect tool,down in the console, I see the result showing up in my HTML [you can see it here, the data is shown in green square](https://i.stack.imgur.com/agsnl.jpg)
but in the actual output HTML it doesn't show anything.
[again the green square in here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cEdt0.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try modifying the code as below:

```
$(document).on('click', 'a.SearchResultItem', e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    targetAuthorityId = e.target.parentElement.id;

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '../supremeWatchShowData/',
        data: {
            'csrfmiddlewaretoken': csrf,
            'authorityId': targetAuthorityId,
        },
        success: (res) => {
            console.log(res);
            // Update the table cell with the received data
            $('#TABLECELLID').text(res.lprice);
        },
        error: (err) => {
            console.log(err);
        }
    });
});
```

`'TABLECELLID'` is the actual ID or selector for the table cell.

Django view modified code:

```py
from django.http import JsonResponse

def supremeWatchShowData(request):
    is_ajax = request.headers.get('X-Requested-With') == 'XMLHttpRequest'
    if is_ajax: 
        authorityId = request.POST.get('authorityId')
        res = get_object_or_404(SourceData, id=authorityId)
        return JsonResponse({'lprice': res.lprice})
    else:
        print("Not an AJAX request")

    return render(request, 'ahromApp/supremeWatch.html')
```

Comment: thank you soooooo much, it worked perfectly fine,  I just did a silly mistake typing out your solution the first time. but when I fixed it. it worked. thankyou